# how to print the content in wordpress php by passing the string

Tags: php, wordpress

how to print the content in wordpress by passing the string php.I have written the following code but it print all the content including image.I want it to print only particular text.

```
<?php

$content = get_the_content('Read more');
print $content;

?>
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether or not you're in the Loop - if you are then your code should work - see more here: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

However, if you are outside the loop and want to pass in a post ID as a paramter, you can refer to this post as everything is explained very well in there: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51741/get-post-content-from-outside-the-loop

```
$page_id = 302;
$page_object = get_page( $page_id );
echo $page_object->post_content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the_excerpt for only showing small content with read more

```
<?php $short_desc= get_the_excerpt();
    echo substr($short_desc,0,200);?>
```

Comment: I want to print first 200 word of content.How can i do.

Comment: <?php $short_desc= get_the_excerpt();
                   
   echo substr($short_desc,0,200);?>

Comment: This print only first 200 character.I want to print first 200 word of the content,please help me.